# Angular 1.x passing data to transcluded markup

Tags: angularjs

```js
class Dashboard {
    static get controller() { return [Dashboard]; }
    static get controllerAs() { return 'vm'; }
    static get template() { return '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'; }
    static get transclude() { return true; }

    constructor() {
        this.name="Bob";
    }
}

class InfoPanel {
    static get template() { return '<span>My name is {{vm.value}}!</span>'; }
    static get controller() { return [InfoPanel]; }
    static get controllerAs() { return 'vm'; }
    static get bindings() {
        return {
            value: '<'
        };
    }

    constructor() {
    }
}


angular.module("dashboardApp", [])
    .component("dashboard", Dashboard)
    .component("infoPanel", InfoPanel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>

<body ng-app="dashboardApp">
    <dashboard>
      <info-panel value="vm.name"></info-panel>
    </dashboard>
</body>
```

I'm trying to pass some component data to it's transcluded markup but I'm getting undefined. Is this possible where vm.name is part of the dashboard component?

```
<dashboard>
    <info-panel info-data="vm.name"></info-panel>
</dashboard>
```

It works if I don't use transclusion and just have the info-panel inside the dashboard template but I think visually it looks better to allow it more inline to the dashboard itself.

Comment: it is possible, mostly code issue and cant say anything without looking at code

Comment: updated with example. notice how the name isn't passed to info-panel's value binding so in it's template it doesn't display anything. I can only assume the bindings aren't done before the transclusion? If so any way around it?